# What could cause a K-means clustering algorithm to converge into a single cluster?

Tags: clustering, python, k-means

I am currently writing a K-means clustering algorithm in Python, and I seem to have coded myself into a corner...  I begin my algorithm with data sets assigned randomly to the appropriate number of K clusters, but I always end up converging to a single cluster (convergence time depends on value of K).  The only case where this doesn't happen is when K=N, my number of data sets.  In that case, I keep 31 clusters (as expected - you can't be closer to anyone than yourself).  The code requires specific file formatting, but I can supply some examples upon request.  I've put the code at the bottom of the post (it's rather bulky), but my logic is as follows:

1. Randomly assign N models (of size M) to K clusters
2. Average the models in each K
3. Calculate similarity (in place of euclidean distance) between N models and each K cluster
4. Assign N models to "closest" similarity K.
5. Repeat

For benchmarking purposes, 31 data sets initialized to 4 clusters will converge to a single cluster in 3-5 iterations.

```
    import numpy as np
    from math import pow,sqrt

    ################### Function for scoring the differences between clusters ############################
    def Score(PROFILES):
            NUM=len(PROFILES)
            scores=np.zeros((NUM,NUM))
            for x in range(NUM):
                    for y in range(x+1,NUM):
                            scores[x,y]=Similarity(PROFILES[x],PROFILES[y])
                            scores[y,x]=scores[x,y]
                            scores[y,y]=0
            return scores
    ######################################################################################################

    ################################### Function for calculating the score 'distance' between two clusters #
    def Similarity(PROFILE1,PROFILE2):
            profile1=np.log(PROFILE1)
            profile2=np.log(PROFILE2)
            sum=0
            for idx in range(len(profile1)):
               sum+=pow(profile1[idx]-profile2[idx],2)/(2*(0.1**2)) # Denominator is approximate error, numerator is difference in I(q)
            score=sqrt(sum)
            return score
    ######################################################################################################

    ########### Determine Initial Clusters ###############################################################
    def FirstGrouping(PROFILES,K):
            Nprofiles=len(PROFILES)
            CLUST_IDX=np.random.randint(1,K+1,size=Nprofiles) #Assign each profile a cluster number
            AVERAGES=AverageCluster(PROFILES,CLUST_IDX) #Calculate cluster Average Profile
            return CLUST_IDX,AVERAGES #List of cluster numbers and KxN array of cluster average profiles
    ######################################################################################################

    ########## Calculate average of profiles in each cluster #############################################
    def AverageCluster(PROFILES,CLUST_IDX):
            CLUSTER_AVERAGE=np.zeros((np.amax(CLUST_IDX),len(PROFILES[0]))) # Initialize a KxN array to store the I(q) (for N q-values) for the K clusters
            for CLUSTER in CLUST_IDX:
                    PROFILES_IN_CLUST=np.where(CLUST_IDX==CLUSTER)[0] # Find the profiles belonging to CLUSTER
                    NUMBER_IN_CLUST=len(PROFILES_IN_CLUST) # Count the total number in the cluster
                    for PROFILE in PROFILES_IN_CLUST:
                            CLUSTER_AVERAGE[CLUSTER-1]+=PROFILES[PROFILE] #Calculate the sum of the scattering profiles
                    CLUSTER_AVERAGE[CLUSTER-1]=CLUSTER_AVERAGE[CLUSTER-1]/NUMBER_IN_CLUST #Divide by number in cluster to get the average

            return CLUSTER_AVERAGE # KxN array
    ######################################################################################################

    ############## Find closest Center (Cluster average) for each profile ################################
    def FindClosest(PROFILES,CLUST_IDX,CLUSTERS): #MxN array of individual profiles, K-array of cluster identities, KxN array of cluster average profiles
            NEW_CLUSTERS=np.copy(CLUST_IDX) #Keep the old cluster index, but make a copy for editing to the new one
            for profile in range(len(PROFILES)):
                    Similarity_to_clusters=np.zeros(len(CLUSTERS)) #Initialize a length K array to store similarity values within
                    for cluster in range(len(CLUSTERS)):
                            Similarity_to_clusters[cluster]=Similarity(PROFILES[profile],CLUSTERS[cluster])
                            print("Profile %i, Cluster %i - %f" % (profile,cluster,Similarity_to_clusters[cluster]))
                    NEW_CLUSTERS[profile]=np.where(Similarity_to_clusters==np.amin(Similarity_to_clusters))[0]+1 #Assign the profile to the closest cluster in similarity
                    NEW_AVERAGE=AverageCluster(PROFILES,NEW_CLUSTERS)

            return NEW_CLUSTERS,NEW_AVERAGE,CLUST_IDX,CLUSTERS  #new cluster dictionary, new cluster average, old cluster dictionary, old cluster average
    ######################################################################################################

    ################# Function for stopping the while loop ###############################################
    def StopCondition(OLD_CLUSTER,NEW_CLUSTER,ITERATION,MAX):
            if ITERATION > MAX: # Stop if you have surpassed max iteration count
                    print("Cluster search reached maximum number of iterations(%i)" % MAX)
                    return 1
            print(np.array_equal(NEW_CLUSTER,OLD_CLUSTER))
            if np.array_equal(NEW_CLUSTER,OLD_CLUSTER): # Stop if you have no change in cluster identities
                    print("Cluster search has converged! (after %i iterations)" % ITERATION)
                    return 1
    ######################################################################################################

    ########### Function for K-Means Clustering of Profiles ##############################################
    def KMeansClustering(PROFILES,K):

            #Bookkeeping variables
            iteration=0
            max_iteration=100

            #Assign first group of clusters
            old_idx=None
            new_idx,new_avg=FirstGrouping(PROFILES,K)

            while not StopCondition(old_idx,new_idx,iteration,max_iteration):
                    iteration+=1
                    new_idx,new_avg,old_idx,old_avg=FindClosest(PROFILES,new_idx,new_avg)
                    print("OLD:\n"+str(old_idx))
                    print("NEW:\n"+str(new_idx))
            return new_idx,new_avg

    ######################################################################################################

    ################### Run the Clustering ###############################################################
    num=31 # number of data sets
    K=4    # number of desired clusters
    for x in range(num):
            if x==0:
                    profiles=np.genfromtxt("file."+str(x),usecols=2,skip_header=3)
            else:
                    profiles=np.vstack((profiles,np.genfromtxt("file"+str(x),usecols=2,skip_header=3)

    cluster_index,cluster_average=KMeansClustering(profiles,K)
    print(cluster_index)
    print("Clustering complete.")
    ######################################################################################################
```

Comment: What do you mean by data sets?

Comment: I'm trying to cluster solution scattering curves, so my PROFILES variable is an NxM array for the N different scattering curves of length M (I have scattering intensities for M different scattering angles).  I assign each curve to a random cluster to begin the algorithm.  I apologize if I have slaughtered the semantics.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not able to answer this (partially due to my limited Python knowledge). Have you considered using an already-implemented k-means? Isn't there one in sci-kit learn?